# remove network connection windows 7

Tags: networking, sharing

I am using windows 7 network share to share files among students. Windows 7 only allows 20 concurrent connections. Some student forgot to disconnect so that no other student can connect. 
Use "net session" command will show me the IP address and user name. Is there a command to disconnect a connection?

Comment: `NET SESSION
[\\computername] [/DELETE] [/LIST]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this needs to be done after a class or session for all Student connections, the easiest solution is to just reboot the Windows 7 machine.